# JS Garbage Collector

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

JS GC has two spaces: the young and the old spaces. Firstly, any variable allocation happens in the young space and after some of them may be promoted to the old collection. Young collections are limited to 1-16MB. I have a question: if a developer declares variable whose size is more than the size of the young space what happens? Is this variable promoted to old space directly?

Comment: You don't declare variables with their size in JS - so no, the value will grow and when it reaches the limit it will be moved. (Although afaik really big objects, like image buffers etc, are allocated in a separate space anyway)

Comment: @Bergi Could you help to understand what this article talks about
     ```Don’t add large files to memory
This one is obvious and well known. If you have large files to process, for example a large CSV file, read it line-by-line and process in little chunks instead of loading the entire file to memory. There are rather rare cases where a single line of csv would be larger than 1mb, thus allowing you to fit it in New Space.```
[link](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/debugging-memory-leaks-node-js-applications)

Comment: It means that streaming is faster than loading complete files at once.

Comment: @Bergi what about ```fit it New Space```

Comment: It just says that it's expected that a single stream item fits in the "New Space".

Comment: @Bergi ok, if the size of chunk (a single stream item) fits in the New Space then it allocates in New Space. What happens if the size of chunk doesn't fit the size for New Space?

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong as mB-sized chunks should not occur anywhere :-) But it just would get allocated elsewhere, and the garbage collector would likely collect it later, i.e. less efficiently.

Comment: )) Does it mean that this chunk may be allocated in the Old space straightway skipping Young generation where GC algorithm more effective?

Comment: More likely the "*Large Object Space*". But it really depends on from where an object (probably string or buffer) that large comes from.

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand the following phrase: `Avoid large objects in hot functions
Ideally you want to avoid large objects inside of hot functions so that all data is fit into New Space.` I predict, that in New Space JS uses more effective algorithm (Scavenge) and GC doesn't take a lot of time. For old Generation JS uses Mark-Sweet algorithm which takes more time. Therefore if we're trying to allocate a big object (the size is bigger than the size of New Space) in a hot function it's directly allocated in Old Space with less efficient algorithm. Otherwise I don't understand the sense.

Comment: It's not really that the algorithm is "faster" or "more effective" than the other. It's just that the GC strategy for new space is optimised for small objects that get quickly allocated, are not referenced a lot, and get quickly deallocated again. If you create (and forget) a lot of large objects in hot code (that runs often) you put more pressure on the allocator, and GC becomes less efficient overall.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks ) it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how a garbage collector works (e.g. whether it uses a [semi-space young generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Implementation_strategies)) is implementation-dependent, i.e. varies between different javascript runtimes, and not all that important unless you want to get deep into performance-optimization territory.

The behavior you describe there is particular to a specific implementation and not a general property of the standardized javascript language.

What is important that collectors provide the behavior mandated by the specification. And the specification does not say anything about a specific size threshold such as 16MiB after which objects should be treated differently.

> Is this variable promoted to old space directly?

That would be one possible implementation strategy.